# Mount VM's hard disk on Windows 7 machine?

Tags: virtualization, mount

I have a VM setup on VMWare's Esx server, which I access via normal Putty or ssh (over normal LAN network, using VPN)
Is there a way to mount my VM's hard-disk directly on my Win 7 machine, so that I can use and access it as a normal external storage device ?

Comment: As this isn't a programming question, it's not appropriate to Stack Overflow. You might have better luck at SuperUser.com

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you don't quite want to do what Aaron Miller is suggesting, so correct me if I'm wrong.

Since your VM disk is in VMDK format, it can't be mounted directly to your Win7 machine.  However, Win7 supports something called a Virtual Hard Drive (VHD) and here is an article that tells you how to use V2V (virtual to virtual) Image Converter to convert your VMDK into a VHD that you can then mount on your Win7 machine: http://www.petri.co.il/converting-vmware-files.htm#

Please let me know if this helps or not, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ESX uses the same (.vmdk) virtual disk format as VMware Workstation, which appears to be the case, [this](http://www.vmware.com/download/eula/diskmount_ws_v55.html) VMware utility should do the job.